# Concat two subqueries into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to concat two of my subqueries together.

Is there a trick to allow this to happen? It doesn't like my '||' after the first subquery

```
Select 
    pi.name || ',' || pi.lastName || ',' || 
    (select middleName from MiddleNameTable where id = pi.id) MiddleName || ',' 
    || (select formalName from formalName where id = pi.id) formalName 
from 
    mytable pi
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes - you can do it if syntax is correct (sample data in lines #1 - 7; query begins at line #8):

```
SQL> with
  2  mytable (id, name, lastname) as
  3    (select 1, 'Brand', 'Erson' from dual),
  4  middlenametable (id, middlename) as
  5    (select 1, 'S' from dual),
  6  formalname (id, formalname) as
  7    (select 1, 'Overflow' from dual)
  8  Select pi.name || ',' || pi.lastName || ',' ||
  9    (select m.middleName from MiddleNameTable m where m.id = pi.id)  || ','
 10  ||(select f.formalName from formalName f      where f.id = pi.id)  as full_name
 11  from mytable pi;

FULL_NAME
----------------------
Brand,Erson,S,Overflow
```

But, why would you do it that way? What's wrong with a simple join?

```
SQL> with
  2  mytable (id, name, lastname) as
  3    (select 1, 'Brand', 'Erson' from dual),
  4  middlenametable (id, middlename) as
  5    (select 1, 'S' from dual),
  6  formalname (id, formalname) as
  7    (select 1, 'Overflow' from dual)
  8  select pi.name ||','|| pi.lastname ||','|| m.middlename ||','|| f.formalname as full_name
  9  from mytable pi left join middlenametable m on m.id = pi.id
 10                  left join formalname f      on f.id = pi.id;

FULL_NAME
----------------------
Brand,Erson,S,Overflow

SQL>
```

Comment: Better would be to use *outer* join to get the exact same result as with the subquery in all cases...

Comment: Yes, it would, @Marmite. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was dumb, I don't need the middleName Alias

I should just it without the middle alias since i'm joining all together anyway

```
Select pi.name || ',' || pi.lastName || ',' || 
(select middleName from MiddleNameTable where id = pi.id) || ',' 
||(select formalName from formalName where id = pi.id) as fullName
from mytable pi
```

Answer (score 0):

I show you my option, maybe you'll think why you need **CONCAT** function if it is only for two arguments...
I use it sometimes because is more clean.
The point is there, is **CONCAT** accept only two arguments, but you can do nested function.

```
SELECT 
    'PERICO' || ',' || 
    'DE' || ',' || 
    CONCAT(
        (SELECT 'LOS' || ',' FROM DUAL), 
        (SELECT 'PALOTES' FROM DUAL)) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT('PERICO' || ',',
                'DE' || ',')
                ,
        CONCAT(
            (SELECT 'LOS' || ',' FROM DUAL), 
            (SELECT 'PALOTES' FROM DUAL))
    )
FROM DUAL;
```

result --> PERICO,DE,LOS,PALOTES